# RequestMapping conversion exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring RequestMapping that is taking a JSON structure and converting it to a POJO. If I send the route a malformed JSON structure, I get back a "400 Bad Request" but what I'd like to receive is an error message stating why it was a bad request. I have a Validator also checking the JSON structure, but it seems that it's not called if the structure is unable to be converted. Is there a way in which I can access the built in HttpMessageConverter errors or exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) for this, by overriding the `handleHttpMessageNotReadable` method.

From: [17.11.3 Handling Standard Spring MVC Exceptions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-rest-spring-mvc-exceptions):

> If you prefer to write error content via @ExceptionHandler methods you can extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler instead. This is a convenient base for @ControllerAdvice classes providing an @ExceptionHandler method to handle standard Spring MVC exceptions and return ResponseEntity. That allows you to customize the response and write error content with message converters. See the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler javadocs for more details.

An example usage of the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` can be found here: http://www.jayway.com/2013/02/03/improve-your-spring-rest-api-part-iii/

Otherwise you can find more spring mvc exception handling approaches here:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

If your needs aren't too complex you might just want to use a [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#simplemappingexceptionresolver)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe it has started me on the correct path to resolving this issue. I added a simple `@ExceptionHandler` to my Controller in question and noticed something strange. When I try sending JSON data to the route, I get a `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'group/person' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`. At this point, I'm not even sure if the route even receives the malformed JSON data since the route itself cannot be found. If I send a well-formed JSON structure however, the route gets called just fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you are making progress.
Something sounds a bit strange, if you post a cut-down example of your problem that could shed some more light what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

**ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** is used to identify the Spring ***MVC specific*** exceptions & to implement a common error response handling **strategy** for them.

It consists of many methods for example:

1. handleMissingServletRequestParameter > handle if invalid request **params**
2. handleHttpMessageNotReadable > handles if invalid request **body**
3. handleExceptionInternal  > A **single place** to customize the response body of **all** exception types.

The below mentioned code overrides **handleExceptionInternal** method

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class JavaWebExeptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    public class ExpnDetails {
        public int expnCode;
        public String expnMessage;
    }

    // A single place to customize the response body of all exception types.
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<ExpnDetails> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body, 
                     HttpHeaders headers,HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ExpnDetails(status.value(), ex.getMessage()), status);
    }
}
```

So all the Spring ***MVC specific*** exception are handled at one place and **ExpnDetails** object is sent as response **body** which consists of a expnCode & expnMessage.

Output:

```
{
    "expnCode": 415,
    "expnMessage": "Content type 'application/json1' not supported"
}

{
    "expnCode": 400,
    "expnMessage": "JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('"
    ' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('
    "' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 4]"
}
```

**Note** this solution also helps in hiding container(ex. tomcat server) details to appear in response error when request fails.